# Нужны ли здесь какие-то запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

В  верхней   части  шпинделя  под  резьбой  расположена  крышка  12  сальника, а  под ней  в  кольцевом  канале  крышки  корпуса  находится  сальниковая  набивка  10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дополнительные запятые не нужны.

**P.S.**

Смущает указание "**под** резьбой". Не берусь, не видя конструкции,  судить, насколько правильно или неправильно такое сочетание, но... По-моему, всё-таки, употреблён не совсем подходящий к описанию места расположения этой крышки предлог.

Comment: Спасибо большое.